# Can't scale this face uniformly no matter where I put the origin point

Tags: modeling, transforms

I'm trying to scale the inside face of this object evenly so I get a more sloping bevel at the edges. However it refuses to scale evenly. The top edge barely moves inward.

I've reset all transforms. Tried changing the pivot point. I have also tried adjusting the Transform Orientations to 3D cursor but the result is the same no matter where I place the cursor. I've also tried constraining the scale on every possible axis to see if it makes any difference. I always get the same result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to inset the face ? It usually does the trick with complex faces.

Either that or Alt + S ?

Answer (score 0):

Insetting just created yet more edges. I found a workaround which was to simply to drag the top face slightly down on the y access and then scale on the x axis by the same amount.